# Properties.loadFromXML NullPointerException with jUnit

Tags: java, xml, properties, junit, classloader

I have the problem with loading properties from xml inside jUnit test (the same code works well without jUnit):

```
public class InternetMapTest {

private Properties properties;

@Before
public void readProperties() {

try {
ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("analyse.properties.xml");
properties.loadFromXML(stream);
```

...

if I run test, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.analyse.tests.InternetMapTest.readProperties(InternetMapTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    ...
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Unfortunately, I can't identify the problem using this stack trace. First of all, I thought that the file was not found (it's located in /src/test/resources). But
   System.out.println(loader.getResource("analyse.properties.xml"));
returns correct file path.

Can somebody help, please?

I use STS 2.9.1 with Maven (plugin version 2.3.1, as I think) and jUnit 4.10 under Ubuntu 12.04 amd64.

Thank you in advance,
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable "properties" may be null, you would have to create it before calling the loading function.